# xcodebuild -exportArchive fails for tvOS apps

Tags: xcode7, xcodebuild, ipa, tvos

If I tried to export an `.ipa` from an `.xcarchive` using the command line using `xcodebuild` as such:

```
xcodebuild archive -scheme "Cross" -archivePath "build/Cross.xcarchive"
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "build/Cross.xcarchive" -exportPath "build/Cross-tvOS.ipa"
```

it fails with the error "the platform is unknown: appletvos":

```
+ xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath build/Cross.xcarchive -exportFormat app -exportPath build/Cross-tvOS.ipa
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: -exportArchive without -exportOptionsPlist is deprecated
2015-11-30 22:13:44.403 xcodebuild[42874:30912505] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-9081/IDEFoundation/Execution/Archiving/IDEArchivedApplication.m:148
Details:  Asked if we support packaging as a given format, but the platform is unknown: appletvos
Object:   <IDEArchivedApplication: 0x7f89bea3e990>
Method:   -supportsPackagingAsFormat:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f89bbc320d0>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
error: archive at path '/Users/pol/Downloads/Cross/tvOS/build/Cross.xcarchive' cannot be exported as APP
** EXPORT FAILED **
```

I can successfully export the `.ipa` using the Xcode Organizer. This was observed on Xcode version 7.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the error message is misleading. This failure happens if you don't specify the `-exportOptionsPlist` argument.

Even passing a fake empty `.plist` file like this fixes the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict/>
</plist>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how this solves the problem, it only sounds like you are explaining something else that causes the issue you were facing. Your original question does not use the plist option at all so this answer does not seem to fit as a solution.

Comment: Not really, that's actually the point: the failure is if you don't pass the `-exportOptionsPlist` argument, which I wasn't doing.

Comment: This makes more sense now, thank you for editing the text.